# Fullscreen landscape Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, fullscreen, landscape, android-fullscreen

I have a dialog (that contains a video player by ExoPlayer) that is created like this:

```
dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen) {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }

    @Override
         public void onBackPressed() {
               if (exoPlayerFullscreen)
                      closeFullscreenDialog();
               super.onBackPressed();
         }
 };
```

This way, the video is showed in landscape mode but not in fullscreen. If I remove `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)`, the video is played in fullscreen but in portrait mode. How can I get the video show up in both (fullscreen and landscape mode)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `cool icon` and on the click of the icon change the orientation at runTime. .

```
 @Override
 onClick(View v) {

   if(flag_landscape)         

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo
           .SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

   else         

     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo
                 .SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

  }
```